# Dependency injection issue with Azure Functions, .NET6, and MediatR 12

Tags: dependency-injection, mediatr

Frustrating error I have never seen before and cannot shake it. Using simple Azure HTTP Function in .NET 6 and MediatR 12 and getting the following in Startup.cs for DI of MediatR:

> System.MissingMethodException
> HResult=0x80131513
> Message=Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor.get_IsKeyedService()'.
>
> Source=MediatR
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at MediatR.Registration.ServiceRegistrar.<>c.b__12_0(ServiceDescriptor service)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__61`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
> at MediatR.Registration.ServiceRegistrar.RegisterBehaviorIfImplementationsExist(IServiceCollection services, Type behaviorType, Type subBehaviorType)
> at MediatR.Registration.ServiceRegistrar.AddRequiredServices(IServiceCollection services, MediatRServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMediatR(IServiceCollection services, MediatRServiceConfiguration configuration)
> at TheMove.Functions.Startup.Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) in C:\Users\shamu\source\repos\TheMove\TheMove.Functions\Startup.cs:line 25
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.ConfigureAndLogUserConfiguredServices(IWebJobsStartup startup, WebJobsBuilderContext context, IWebJobsBuilder builder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseWebJobsStartup(IWebJobsBuilder builder, Type startupType, WebJobsBuilderContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseExternalStartup(IWebJobsBuilder builder, IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator startupTypeLocator, WebJobsBuilderContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(HostBuilderContext context, IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder)

Source Code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(TheMove.Functions.Startup))]
namespace TheMove.Functions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public Startup() { }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            if(builder != null)
            {
                var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("TheMove.Application");
                builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, but downloading version 12.1.1 and doing a clean and a rebuild fixed it for me.

Comment: strange, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove MediatR from other projects, after updating to 12.1.1 as A.Grefslie suggested.

*Had a test project and another project, which implicitly was adding MediatR and referring to the project with ServiceCollection*

*Ran into the same issue again with version 12.2.0, downgraded to 12.1.1 and it worked*

Comment: strange, but this worked for me.